# How to keep one div behind another animated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu bar with some icons, when the user places the mouse over an icon I show an animated div which is "part" of a complete div. So far so good.

The problem is that the animated div slides down the div that should be behind... If I use position:absolute doesn't work...

(I read all the related questions but none solves my problem)

This is the Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/yhc1azb4/27/

The HTML

```
<div id="menu">                        
    <ul class="itemMenu">
        <i id="item1">1</i>
    </ul>                                            
</div>                    

<div id="preview">    
</div>                            

<div id="home">                
    <p>This text should not slide down...</p>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
div#menu {      
    padding-left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #000;   
}

div#preview {  
    position: relative; /* with "absolute" it doesn't work */ 
    z-index: 10;    
}

div#home {  
    z-index: 3;
    display: block;
    position: relative;                
}

.itemMenu {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #000;   
}

.itemMenu i {
    font-size:2.5em;    
    color:#fff;
    background: #000;
    transition: background 0.2s linear 0s;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 25px;    
    position: relative;
}

.itemMenu i:hover {
    transition: background 0.2s linear 0s;    
    cursor: pointer;
}

.itemMenu i#item1:hover { background: #0000FF; }

.appear {
    z-index: 5;
    max-height: 1080px;    
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1);
}
```

And the JS

```
$("document").ready(function() {                     
    $('.itemMenu i').mouseover(showPreview);
    $('.itemMenu i').mouseout(showPreview);
});                

function showPreview() {    

    var itemSelected = $(this).attr("id");   
    var action = event.type;     
    var prevShowDiv = '#preview';

    switch (itemSelected) {                
        case 'item1':
            var itemToChangeID = '#item1';
            var divToShowID    = '#div1';                     
            var backColor      = '#0000FF';
            var iconColor      = '#000';
            break;                                        
    }               

    if (action=='mouseover') {                    
        $("#preview").css("height", 20);                    
        $(prevShowDiv).css("background", backColor);                    
        $(prevShowDiv).addClass("appear");                           
    }

    if (action=='mouseout') {
        $("#preview").css("height", 0);                
        if ($("#preview").hasClass("appear")) { 
            $("#preview").removeClass("appear"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: absolute;
top: 70px;` 
to div#home.  This will keep the positioning of the text where you want it.  The 70px is based on the current height of your `.itemMenu` div so you can change it as necessary. To read a bit more about it, this is a great article on positioning: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/.  I have your working fiddle here:

```js
$("document").ready(function() {                     
    $('.itemMenu i').mouseover(showPreview);
    $('.itemMenu i').mouseout(showPreview);
});                

function showPreview() {    

    var itemSelected = $(this).attr("id");   
    var action = event.type;     
    var prevShowDiv = '#preview';

    switch (itemSelected) {                
        case 'item1':
            var itemToChangeID = '#item1';
            var divToShowID    = '#div1';                     
            var backColor      = '#0000FF';
            var iconColor      = '#000';
            break;                                        
    }               

    if (action=='mouseover') {                    
        $("#preview").css("height", 20);                    
        $(prevShowDiv).css("background", backColor);                    
        $(prevShowDiv).addClass("appear");                           
    }
    
    if (action=='mouseout') {
        $("#preview").css("height", 0);                
        if ($("#preview").hasClass("appear")) { 
            $("#preview").removeClass("appear"); 
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
div#menu {      
    padding-left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #000;   
}

div#preview {  
    position: relative; /* with "absolute" it doesn't work */ 
    z-index: 10;    
}

div#home {  
    z-index: 3;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
}

.itemMenu {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #000;   
}

.itemMenu i {
    font-size:2.5em;    
    color:#fff;
    background: #000;
    transition: background 0.2s linear 0s;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 25px;    
    position: relative;
}

.itemMenu i:hover {
    transition: background 0.2s linear 0s;    
    cursor: pointer;
}

.itemMenu i#item1:hover { background: #0000FF; }

.appear {
 z-index: 5;
 max-height: 1080px;    
 transition-property: all;
 transition-duration: .5s;
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">                        
    <ul class="itemMenu">
        <i id="item1">1</i>
    </ul>                                            
</div>                    

<div id="preview">    
</div>                            

<div id="home">                
    <p>This text should not slide down...</p>
</div>
```

Good Luck.